# How can i sort checked checkbox items and send them to labels in vb

Tags: vb.net, sorting, checkbox

i want to write a mechanical eng. software to calculate kitchen hood exhaust flow rate and make a report.
firstly, user will check the calculate button, secondly user will check gas or electric and then user will enter the area.
[image: form1]

for example, user select two random types(there are 40 types of kitchen hoods) and selects gas and enters areas. i will make calculation from these selections but my problem is: i can't write them to second form with sorting the selected ones. 
[image: form2]

you can see label 1, label2 etc. i can send the selected box text to labels with if statement:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            Form2.Label1.Text = Label5.Text
End If
```

but i don't know which one will selected and i will have 40 types but in report part (form2) i will have maximum 10 types(because of the general layout of kitchen designs). so i want to sort selected ones and add report form without any blank rows.

i'm really sorry for my poor English.

Comment: You keep saying "sort" but I think you actually mean "filter".  Are you saying that you only want the second form to display rows from the first form where the "Calculate" box is checked?  If you really do mean "sort" then what exactly are you intending to sort by?

Comment: Yes, exactly i want this. i said sort because i think that i must sort the checked ones 1 to 10 and at the report form labels shows the data 1 to 10 . "Filter" is absolutely correct, thank you.

Comment: So, if you want the first ten or fewer check boxes from a list then you can do this: `myList.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).Take(10)`.  You simply have to put all the `CheckBox` controls into a list first.  You could then use those `CheckBox` controls to get the other data from, for instance, a `Dictionary` that you also created earlier.  In fact, that could be tacked onto the previous expression: `myList.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).Take(10).Select(Function(cb) myDictionary(cb))`.  That will give back the values stored in the `Dictionary` against the first 10 or fewer checked boxes.